# Avoid showing default title when a fragment is displayed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar, fragment, title

I am working on the codelab:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-add-navigation/index.html?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#0

I have the following function in the GameFragment.kt

```
private fun setTitle() {
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = getString(R.string.title_android_trivia_question, questionIndex + 1, numQuestions)
}
```

strings.xml contains this line:

```
    <string name="title_android_trivia_question" formatted="false">Android Trivia (%d/%d)</string>
```

I call this function in the onCreateView like this:

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentGameBinding>(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_game, container, false)

    // Shuffles the questions and sets the question index to the first question.
    randomizeQuestions()
    
    setTitle()

    ...
```

This displays the title properly. But before showing this the default title "GameFragment" is shown for a fraction of second. How to avoid that?

Comment: Why do you have an `android:label` in your navigation graph if you don't want to use that label?

Comment: You've to use `android:label` in your navigation graph to set the title for your `fragment`. You don't have to manually set the `title` like you are doing now.

Comment: Removing the android:label line from navigation graph solved the problem. The title changes for each question. Like (1/5), (2/5), ... That is why it is specified in code. Can I specify a string with %/%s in label and let it change the title?

Comment: To make the title dynamic, is there an equivalent way to specify getString(R.string.title_android_trivia_question, questionIndex + 1, numQuestions) in android:label in navigation xml?